# how to collect browsing data of users from my website? is there a way to do that

Tags: cookies

how to collect the browsing history of users like google and Facebook do. I want to collect data from my users. Is there a way I can collect the browsing history of my users?

Comment: So, can you answer it??

Answer (score -1):

1. You can either use Google Analytics application to collect the analyze the data for you or
2. You can use amazon tools such as [Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/kinesis-examples.html) to stream data and use Kinesis Analytics to analyze it.